# 「僕は任務を完成〔する／した〕かどうかを確認しました。」

Tags: grammar, tense

1. 僕は任務を完成**した**かどうかを確認しました。
2. 僕は任務を完成**する**かどうかを確認しました。

According to my understanding, the first is correct. But some people say that it is the second, which one is right and why?

Comment: 「任務を**完成**する」 sounds unnatural... I'd say 任務を[完了]{かんりょう}する, 任務を[全]{まっと}うする (accomplish/complete one's mission), 任務を[遂行]{すいこう}する(carry out/perform one's mission)

Answer (score 3):

Both sound weird. You should instead say 僕は任務が完了したかどうかを確認しました, or 僕は任務が完了しそうか確認しました. 僕は任務が完了するか確認しました is not wrong but しそうか sounds more natural.

In general 完成 is used for things, while 完了 is used for actions.

Answer (score 1):

The first one means that you have confirmed that you finished something.
The second one just seems weird and incorrect to me. Maybe it would make more sense if you add べき after する so then it would mean that you have confirmed that you have to finish something.

Answer (score -1):

> 1. (僕は) 作業が完成したかどうかを確認しました。
> 2. (僕は) 作業が完成するかどうかを確認しました。

To me,  these seem like  ...

(1)　[The checking occurs after starting on the task] -- I checked to see if I had completed the task.

(2)　[The checking occurs any time before finishing the task] --

- I  checked to see if I am to complete the task.
- I had checked to see if I am supposed to complete the task.
- 「今朝、今日中に作業が完成するかどうかを確認しました。」
  　(This morning) 　I checked to see if I would complete the task 　(by the end of the day).

<sub>（ 上司に　「確認しました！」　と報告してるような雰囲気で、　「今日中に作業が完成しそうか・・・」　とか　アヤフヤな言い方をしたら、上司によっては　怒られそう　ｗ　）</sub>

The speaker can say 1 or 2 any time after the checking occurs.

Maybe this is related to the [relative tense] issue.  I hope to add some more material to this thread: 
[相対テンス -- ①ハワイへ行く時、帽子を買う。　②ハワイへ行く時、帽子を買った。　③ハワイへ行った時、帽子を買う。 ④ハワイへ行った時、帽子を買った。](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/39648/16344)

<sub>( 任務を完遂, 任務を遂行, 任務を果たす, 任務を全うする, ... may be better, but there were huge number of hits for "任務を完成" also. )</sub>

（　「作業が完成」「事業が完成」は自然に思えるな。　面倒なので検索もしないけど　 <sub>（→【小声で】結局したｗ）</sub>　 　）

だいたいが、「任務」　「mission」　なんて普通の生活では滅多に使わんだろ？ｗ

相対テンス の話をしてるんであって、「表現の自然さ」に執着し過ぎるのはどうなのよ？　
去年の同じ話題では　*「任務を完成」*　（の自然さ）　が全く問題になってないようだが・・・ｗ
[～か　～かどうか　相対テンスの質問](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/27383/16344)

<sub>（まぁ、日本語の性質について別の発見もあったな）</sub>

最初の時点（Ver.）から自己評価では　A　の回答なんだが、UpVoteが一個も付かない理由を推理してみると： 
１．OP氏の知りたい事では無かった。 
２．間髪を入れずに、本サイトでの人気絶大らしきChocoさんのクレームが入ったので、Chocoファン連が全員、遠慮してUpVoteを呉れない。

Comment: 「任務を完成」の検索結果は251件ですが、それって huge number なんでしょうか？　https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E4%BB%BB%E5%8B%99%E3%82%92%E5%AE%8C%E6%88%90%22&ei=EQL2V7T2OKakjwS724awDQ&start=90&sa=N#q=%22%E4%BB%BB%E5%8B%99%E3%82%92%E5%AE%8C%E6%88%90%22&start=250　 それと、ヒットした文章の内容は少しくらい読んでみられましたか？機械翻訳みたいな変な日本語の文のページや、（例えば「探求、があるいは任務を完成する場所が冒険的なことを行います」とか、「壁フライングとフライ飛躍で任務を完成して、私はまだ地上、ない時間」とか、「ことの非本意の地と任務を完成して、からまでで地の底王国はちょうど力強い妖怪として逃がしていて」とか）、中国関係のページ（中国共産党とか日中友好なんとかとか）がずいぶん多いように思われるんですけど・・・。

Comment: 独り言だとでも思って聞き流してくださいね。@Enno さんも`In general 完成 is used for things, while 完了 is used for actions` と書かれてるように、（中国語では違うかもしれませんが、日本語では、）「完成」は**完全にできあがること・仕上げること**という意味ですから「 **作品**が完成する」「 **建物**が完成する」のように「things」に、「完了」は**物事が完全に終わること・終えること**という意味ですから「 **任務**が完了する」「 **作業**が完了する」のように「action」や「event」に使うのが自然です。

Comment: `「表現の自然さ」に執着し過ぎるのはどうなのよ` <- 上のコメントで私が「任務には完成より完了がいい」旨のコメントをしたら、あなたが「there were huge number of hits for "任務を完成"」とおっしゃるので、その検索に関してお返事しただけで、執着しているつもりはなかったのですが・・・。今度は「作業が完成」になっていたので、使い方の違いが判っていらっしゃらないようなので、国語辞典の定義とともに説明したんですが・・・（ところで、自然かどうかをいつもグーグル検索のみで確かめようとするのはちょっと…少納言とかコトノハとかのコーパス使ったほうがよくないですかね。。）`普通の生活では滅多に使わんだろ` <- ??? 普通の生活で使わない、例えば小説や映画でしか見ない表現を、SEで勉強しても別にかまわないと思います。

Comment: `間髪を入れずに、本サイトでの人気絶大らしきChocoさんのクレームが入ったので、Chocoファン連が全員、遠慮してUpV‌​oteを呉れない` <- 人のせいにすんな！ :/ このポストにUVが入らないのはこのポストの内容のせい。あなたの他のポストにもUVがたくさん入らないのも、それぞれの内容のせい‌​。人気があるとかないとか、新入りとか古株‌​とか、関係ない！そもそも、「自然な言い方」「正しい使い方」を教えようとしたら、なんで「クレーム」とか言われなあかんねん！